# FFMPEG Invalid value '1' for option 'loop'

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to run this code (It did work on my previously server, but now i keep getting this annoying error):

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 25 -t 322 -i /home/kampmann/public_html/m/xxx/movie_10262.jpg -q:v 1 -an /home/kampmann/public_html/m/xxxs/573240.mp4 2>&1`

Error:
Invalid value '1' for option 'loop'

Here is my output.

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
 libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
 libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
    libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
 libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
 libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
 libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
 libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0


Invalid value '1' for option 'loop'
```

Answer (score 2):

0.6.5 is ancient. It may use `-loop_input` instead of `-loop 1`, but instead of doing that you should upgrade ffmpeg. [Download a Linux build of ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a step-by-step guide to [compile ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide).